# programmatically check for iPhone's Passcode in settings bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, settings

I want to check for a condition whether my phones passcode is set or not from my application itself, so that i can prompt the user to set a Passcode.

Comment: Just pop up an alert suggesting to the user that they should set a passcode, you can't force them to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its not possible to access the configured passcode with public API.