# How do I require a device-level passcode to use my Phonegap app on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, security, cordova

I want to create an app that requires the user to have a lock code set up on the device.
For example, when I link up to our Exchange server, it requires me to set a lock code on my Android and iOS devices. I would like to enforce the same rules for the app I am developing.

Comment: An app cannot enforce such a restriction on iOS. Only a device profile from an MDM tool or profile manager software can do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337563/programmatically-detect-whether-ios-passcode-is-enabled-or-not